# Java Apache Commons CLI does not find setArgs()

Tags: java, command-line-interface, apache-commons-cli

I am trying to get multiple arguments passed to a java program. The Apache Commons CLI interface has been set up correctly and works. However, when I try to use

`setArgs(Option.UNLIMITED_VALUES)`, it gives me an error

`The method setArgs(int) is undefined for the type Options.`

My code looks like this:

```
import java.io.Console;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.cli.*;


public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    CommandLineParser parser = new BasicParser();

    Options options = new Options();
    options.setArgs(Option.UNLIMITED_VALUES);   
    options.addOption("p", true, "Program under test");
    options.addOption("o", true, "Oracle");
    options.addOption("n", true, "Number of test cases");

    try {
        CommandLine commandline = parser.parse(options, args);

        System.out.println(commandline.getOptionValue("p"));

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Command line failed.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`setArgs`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/cli/Option.html#setArgs-int-) is a method related to `Option` not `Options`

Comment: However, this creates another issue. Now the same line gives me "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setArgs(int) from the type Option". Any clue?

Comment: You're probably calling `Option.setArgs` statically. Create an instance of `Option` before attempting to use `setArgs` on the instance of that class

Comment: You're a lifesaver! Thanks!